# Wordpress include custom page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm sure this is a simple question. But how do I get Wordpress at startup to ignore trying to load a Page or Post and instead load my custom page? When in the Wordpress bootstrap process is it decided which php-page is going to load?

I will have the following url:

bt.local/wp/ads/1

And would like a php-page called ads.php to be loaded and load the ad with adid = 1.

What's the best way to solve this? (there's no Post called ads and there's no Page called Ads).

Thank you!

KR

Josef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the template_redirect action for that - example:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_template_loader');


function my_template_loader() {
    if( get_query_var('adid') ) {
       locate_template(array("your-custom-page.php"), true);
    }
}
```

edit:

in addition to that you need some new rewrite rule to add your custom url - the basic information is here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite

your rule could look something like that:

```
$newrules['ads/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=ads&adid=$matches[1]';
```

this needs a 'placeholder' page called ads to be setup and in addition to that you have to register your new query var `adid` like that:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_adid_var');
function parameter_queryvars($qvars) {
    $qvars[] = ' adid';
    return $qvars;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I used global $wp_query instead of $post in order to extract the pagename: $wp_query->get('pagename'). Then I located the template and loaded my custom ads/index.php file. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just noticed that my $wp_query didn't work when adding an ID to the url. For instance bt.local/wp/ads/1 - the 1 broke it. If I use $post as you suggest, I can't find the pagename "ads" anywhere. How do I do that?

Comment: Just tried it out! Works great! I've added a page called ads which receives the adid thanks to the rewrite rule. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`<?php include('custompage.php'); ?>` ???

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the question is more related to handling the variables and the way wordpress process page loading. For instance - if I created a page called About in WP Admin I would see the About page when entering the URL/WP/About. But if I have a custom page I want to be called when entering URL/WP/Add, how do I make Wordpress find that one? If I enter a Page not created in Wordpress it will say "Page not found". I hope it clarified my question. 

Have a nice evening!

Comment: if it exists in the directory(ies) in which wordpress is looking, it will show up, even not created with wordpress